# How do i display all objects stored in Redis?

Tags: mongodb, redis

Brand new to redis. I've hit redis-cli and i'd expect some simple way of seeing what objects are currently stored in redis...like `"show collections"` in `Mongo`. How do I do this in Redis?

Comment: Commands: http://redis.io/commands

Answer (score 2):

Try keys *

http://redis.io/commands/keys

```
redis> MSET one 1 two 2 three 3 four 4
OK
redis> KEYS *o*
1) "one"
2) "two"
3) "four"
redis> KEYS t??
1) "two"
redis> KEYS *
1) "one"
2) "two"
3) "four"
4) "three"
redis>
```

Comment: and how do you get all values?